# EF readonly view

Tags: frameworks, entity

I have entity based on view which is supposed to be readonly. Another normal entity has 1-to-1 relation to this read only entity.

Read only entity:

**PersonStatictics**

- PersonID
- Stat1
- Stat2

Normal entity

**Person**

- PersonID
- PersonName

Because PersonStatictics is supposed to be read only no stored procedures are attached for DELETE/UPDATE/INSERT actions.

Then I try to delete Person this error occured:

**Unable to update the EntitySet 'PersonStatictics' because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element to support the current operation.**

Google does not help me. 
And I resolve this issue by detaching PersonStatictics before Person deletation.
But I do not like this solution, because I have not to forget to do this for all read only entities.

Is it possible to set for EF that some entity is read only and we do not need to force DELETE/UPDATE/INSERT operations on it?